# .Net SignalR use JWT Bearer Authentication when Cookie Authentication is also configured

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, signalr, bearer-token

I have a ASP.NET 5 WebApp that is part of a bigger system and uses Cookie Authentication for Browser requests.

I want to add the ability to request data and perform specific actions on certain Windows services that are also part of the overall system and are executed on a couple of seperate PCs. I want to use SignalR for this.
Then Windows-Services are running as a dedicated service identity that is part of our ActiveDirectory. Since the services shall not store their user credentials in code or local configuration files, they are requesting an authentication token for the web application from an API that works with Windows Authentication.

Then, when establishing the SignalR connection with the web app, the services will use the token received from the API to authenticate against the web app. This is working in general.

The Authentication configuration of the web app is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
        {
            // Configuration details excluded 
            // ...
            opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    // ...
                }
            };
```

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0) this should be a vaild authentication configuration.

In `services.AddAuthorization(...)` method I've added a policy specific for Bearer scheme:

```
options.AddPolicy("SignalRService", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireRole("SignalRService"); 
    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
});
```

And then there is a SignalR Hub Method secured with this policy:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SignalRService")]
public async Task RegisterService(string clientIdString) { /*...*/ }
```

And finally the hub connection in the windows service is created as follows:

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(hubAddress, options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(authToken);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
```

Establishing the connection works:

```
await connection.StartAsync();
```

But when I try to call the hub method from the windows service like `await connection.InvokeAsync("RegisterService", clientId);` I receive a `HubException` with the message:

> Failed to invoke 'RegisterService' because user is unauthorized

I have also created an API Controller on the web app for testing purposes and secured it with the same policy:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "SignalRService")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(User.Identity.Name);
}
```

When I call this API endpoint with the same token i would user for SignalR Hub call, I get the identity set on the token returned as expected. I also verified that the configured `OnMessageReceived` event handler is executed in this scenario, while it isn't when I use SignalR connection.

When I set `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the default scheme in `Startup.cs` instead of `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` it works also with the SignalR Hub, but then my standard Cookie based user authenticaton breaks.

I expect that there is some additonal configuration necessary to tell the web app to explicitely use the Bearer scheme when a Hub method is called, but I could not find anything so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After desperately trying for another hour, I found out that the specific bearer authentication worked with Cookie authentication as the default, when I put the `Authorize(Policy = "SignalRService")` directly on the class instead of on the method.

Since my hub should also be accessible for browser connections using cookies, I finally ended up with:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Cookies")]
public class SignalRServiceHub : Hub
{
    
    [Authorize(Policy = "SignalRService")]
    public async Task RegisterService(string clientIdString)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "Root")]
    public async Task RegisterMonitoringClient()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure why specifying the Schemes on class level is necessary in this case while it isn't for `ApiController` implementations