# HubConnection Authentication Using Identity From Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, access-token, signalr-hub

I have a Hub that serves up near real-time data. I want the provider of the real-time data to be able to send messages to all connected clients. The problem I am running into is authenticating the connection because the provider is a Windows Service. So, I am creating a client using `HubConnectionBuilder`. When I attempt to connect, I am getting a 401 authentication failure which is expected.

I am trying to figure out how to use the existing Identity authentication that exists in the shared Entity Framework database. Is there a way to get an authentication token using UserManager or SigninManager from this stand-alone service? Or is there a better approach to allow the HubConnection to authenticate?

Here is the connection code I am using:

```
var notifyConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/notify", options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_myAccessToken);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

notifyConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
{
    if (Debug) _logger.LogInformation("Hub connection closed: " + error.Message);
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
    await notifyConnection.StartAsync();
};
try
{
    var task = notifyConnection.StartAsync();
    task.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (Debug) _logger.LogInformation("Hub connection start error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

`_myAccessToken` is not defined. I am trying to figure out how to get a valid access token that will authenticate properly.

EDIT:

I have tried adding JWT authentication. I can verify that the bearer token is getting generated properly. But it doesn't appear to be validated on the `Hub`.

I have added the following to the services configuration:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]));
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, parameters) =>
            expires > DateTime.UtcNow,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateActor = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build(); 
    options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
        {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        });
});
```

I have also updated the `HubConnectionBuilder` to use:

```
notifyConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .WithUrl(baseUrl + "/notify", options =>
  {
      options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
      {
          var stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { username = "****", password = "****" });
          var content = new StringContent(stringData);
          content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
          var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl + "/api/token", content);
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      };
  })
  .WithAutomaticReconnect()
  .Build();
```

It still returns a 401. When I tried to force the `Authorize` attribute to:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Cookies")]
```

It then returns a 500 error.

Comment: Finally got it working. The problem was that the `Authorize` attribute didn't like "Cookies" even though Identity was using them under the hood. Had to specify "Identity.Application" as the other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after changing the `Authorize` attribute on the Hub class, I was able to get JWT authentication working along with the built-in Identity authentication.

Here is the new `Authorize` attribute:

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Identity.Application")]`

I added a simple token generation API controller to feed the HubConnection. The following sources were very helpful:

https://www.codemag.com/article/1807061/Build-Real-time-Applications-with-ASP.NET-Core-SignalR

[.Net SignalR use JWT Bearer Authentication when Cookie Authentication is also configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618850/net-signalr-use-jwt-bearer-authentication-when-cookie-authentication-is-also-co)